# Hibernate not taking taking values entered through a html/jsp fields

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Hello all i am trying to insert some data using hibernate into mysql db.

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Register a Device</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="register.jsp" method="post">  
Make:<input type="text" name="make"/><br><br/>  
Model:<input type="text" name="model"/><br><br/>  
Release Date:<input type="text" name="relDate"/><br><br/>  
Rating:<input type="text" name="rating"/><br><br/>  
Price:<input type="text" name="price"/><br><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="Register"/> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Model Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PHONES")
public class Phone {

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;
@Column(name = "MAKE")
private String make;
@Column(name = "MODEL")
private String model;
@Column(name = "RELEASE_YEAR")
private String relDate;
@Column(name = "RATING")
private String rating;
@Column(name = "PRICE")
private String price;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMake() {
    return make;
}

public void setMake(String make) {
    this.make = make;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public String getRelDate() {
    return relDate;
}

public void setRelDate(String relDate) {
    this.relDate = relDate;
}

public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
```

DAO Class

```
public class PhoneDao {
private static SessionFactory factory;

public static int register(Phone ph) {
    int i = 0;
    Session session = null;
    Transaction t = null;
    try{
    session = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Phone.class).buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    t = session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println(ph.getRating());
    i = (Integer) session.save(ph);
    t.commit();
    }catch(Throwable ex){
        if (t != null)
            t.rollback();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        session.close();
    }
    return i;
}
```

register.jsp

```
Register.jsp

<%@page import="org.nag.hibernate.kudos.Dao.PhoneDao"%>
<jsp:useBean id="u" class="org.nag.hibernate.kudos.model.Phone" />
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="u" />



<%
int i = PhoneDao.register(u);
if (i > 0)
    out.print("You have successfully registered the device");
%>


Record:<br>  
<jsp:getProperty property="make" name="u"/><br>  
<jsp:getProperty property="model" name="u"/><br>  
<jsp:getProperty property="relDate" name="u" /><br>
<jsp:getProperty property="rating" name="u"/><br>  
<jsp:getProperty property="price" name="u" /><br>
```

cfg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property   name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3301/library</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">xxxxxx</property>
    <mapping class="org.nag.hibernate.kudos.model.Phone"/>  
</session-factory>
```

When i am posting it is doing it succesfully in the database but all fileds with null values.

I have used the getProperty of the jsp to see tho/p and there itself it is not taking the fields entered in index.jsp

Please help me out.

Thank you
mark.

Comment: Why don't you post data to servlet instead of jsp?

Comment: Yeah thats a good idea though. That way it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that should set hbm2ddl.auto property to none instead of update.

```
hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3301/library</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">xxxxx</property>
    <mapping class="org.nag.hibernate.kudos.model.Phone"/>   
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```